# Immutable JS - Convert List to Map

Tags: immutable.js

How do I turn

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
```

into

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

via Immutable.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> var map = immutable.Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]);
```

works for me.

```
> map.get('a');
1
```

http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

Comment: Syntax should be `const map = Immutable.Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It works also with `new` keyword but I like it more without it; I'll edit the answer.